# How to convert a file to zip in php

Tags: php, symfony, zip

I have to convert a file rendered in php to zip file.

Here is my code :

```
 $cacheContent = $gRender->getRenderRaw(
                    "feed-google", array(
                    "_context_" => $this->getType(),
                    "_lang_" => $this->getLang()->getId(),
                    "_id_" => $id));


                $cacheDriver->save($cacheKey, $cacheContent, $cacheExpire);
```

Can you help me how to convert cacheContent to zip ?

EDITED: 
In cache folder is genereted a hashfile formated like this : 5d.doctrinecache.data

the file name change everytime is generated. This file inside is looked like this :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <rss version="2.0"  xmlns:g="http://google.com">
                <channel>
                                <title>Item</title>
                    <link></link>
                    <description></description>
                    <language></language>
                    <lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>
                    <generator></generator>

                <item>
  </item>    
        </channel>
    </rss>
```

This file i want to convert in zip

Comment: You can use the [ZipArchive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) method in PHP. [Here is a simple implementation.](https://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$rootPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$backup_name = "exported_zip_file.zip";
$file_name   = "cacheContent.xml";
$file_content = "cacheContent"; // your string
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip -> open($rootPath . "/" . $backup_name, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip -> addFromString($file_name, $file_content);
$zip -> close();

/* this can be deleted */

$zip_final = $rootPath . "/" .$backup_name;
//
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = ".$backup_name);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_final));
//
if(readfile($zip_final)) {
    exit;
}
```

Basically you are defining the name of your zip in $backup_name.

Next you are defining the name of your file in $file_name.

Next you are defining the content from your file in $file_content.

Next you are creating or overwriting a new zip archive.

Next you are creating a new file and adding your $file_content to it.

And finally closing the zip file.

Above the "this can be deleted" are some headers to allow your browser to download your new .zip file

Comment: Warning: dirname() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given i had this warning

Comment: Problem is at  : $zip -> addFile(dirname($rootPath . "/" . $backup_name, $backup_name));   My only change it was to rootPath  , i did :  $rootPath = THELIA_CACHE_DIR . DS . self::FEED_CACHE_DIR;

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new in php and i don't know but i have other problem :  Warning: ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Comment: my_string.txt created but no zip created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210183/discussion-between-pluda-and-alia).

Comment: i'm in the chat now